# Undefined array key 0

Tags: php, wordpress

```
public function get_value( array $options = [] ) {
        
        list( $field, $meta_key ) = Module::get_tag_value_field( $this );

        if ( $field ) {
            $value = $field['value'];

            if ( is_array( $value ) && isset( $value[0] ) ) {
                $value = $value[0];
            }

            if ( $value ) {
                if ( ! isset( $field['return_format'] ) ) {
                    $field['return_format'] = isset( $field['save_format'] ) ? $field['save_format'] : '';
                }

                switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                    case 'email':
                        if ( $value ) {
                            $value = 'mailto:' . $value;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'image':
                    case 'file':
                        switch ( $field['return_format'] ) {
                            case 'array':
                            case 'object':
                                $value = $value['url'];
                                break;
                            case 'id':
                                if ( 'image' === $field['type'] ) {
                                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value, 'full' );
                                    $value = $src[0];
                                } else {
                                    $value = wp_get_attachment_url( $value );
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'post_object':
                    case 'relationship':
                        $value = get_permalink( $value );
                        break;
                    case 'taxonomy':
                        $value = get_term_link( $value, $field['taxonomy'] );
                        break;
                } // End switch().
            }
        } else {
            // Field settings has been deleted or not available.
            $value = get_field( $meta_key );
        } // End if().

        if ( empty( $value ) && $this->get_settings( 'fallback' ) ) {
            $value = $this->get_settings( 'fallback' );
        }

        return wp_kses_post( $value );
    }
```

it says that the error is in this line :

```
list( $field, $meta_key ) = Module::get_tag_value_field( $this );
```

i searched on Google it told me to identify the array befor the if but i  dont know anything about php so can one help me plz by telling me how to solve this error becouse  all my website crashed couse of this error

Comment: please post source code of whole class. There maybe issue in `$this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module::get_tag_value_field( $this) needs to return an array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

You could check for this to avoid an error:

```
$field = [];
$meta_key = null; // Maybe that shoud be = new stdClass();
$tmp = Module::get_tag_value_field($this);
if (is_array($tmp) && array_key_exists(0, $tmp) && array_key_exists(1, $tmp)) {
    list($field, $meta_key) = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: as I don't know what Module does, it's just guessing. Do you get the same error?

Comment: yea same error as before

Comment: I changed the code a bit. Does it work now? What PHP version is running here?

Comment: it worked thank you

Comment: glad to hear that. 